# IBodyModelValidator alternative for Asp .NetCore?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata, xpo

I am using Devexpress XPO as ORM and I am going to create an OData Web API with ASP.NET core. Devexpress has created an [example](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/XPO_how-to-implement-odata4-service-with-xpo) in ASP.NET classic and I have one code line (in CS/ODataService/Globals.asax.cs, Line 13) that I cannot "convert" because there seems to be no counterpart in ASP.NET core:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IBodyModelValidator), new CustomBodyModelValidator());
```

First I am puzzled by ...Services.Replace since I did not find the suitable "command" in core and (most important) in core seems to be no counterpart for IBodyModelValidator. How would I "transform" that into ASP.NET core?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but this is the first post I came across when looking for the answer. Here is how I solved the issue:

```
public class CustomBodyModelValidator : ObjectModelValidator
{
    public CustomBodyModelValidator(IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider, IList<IModelValidatorProvider> validatorProviders) 
        : base(modelMetadataProvider, validatorProviders) { }

    public override ValidationVisitor GetValidationVisitor(ActionContext actionContext, IModelValidatorProvider validatorProvider,
        ValidatorCache validatorCache, IModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, ValidationStateDictionary validationState)
    {
        return new(actionContext, validatorProvider, validatorCache, metadataProvider, validationState)
        {
            ValidateComplexTypesIfChildValidationFails = true
        };
    }
    
    public override void Validate(ActionContext actionContext, ValidationStateDictionary validationState, string prefix, object model,
        ModelMetadata metadata, object container)
    {            
        //TODO: put your logic here
        
        base.Validate(actionContext, validationState, prefix, model, metadata, container);
    }
}
```

And then register it in the `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddSingleton<IObjectModelValidator>(provider =>
{
    var metadataProvider = provider.GetRequiredService<IModelMetadataProvider>();
    var options = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>().Value;
    return new CustomBodyModelValidator(metadataProvider, options.ModelValidatorProviders);
});
```